get metadata from vector store to output using Langchain LCEL RAG chain
I have a langchain LCEL RAG chain with chat history as follows
chain = (
    {
        "question": itemgetter("messages") | RunnableLambda(extract_user_query_string),
        "chat_history": itemgetter("messages") | RunnableLambda(extract_chat_history),
        "formatted_chat_history": itemgetter("messages") | RunnableLambda(format_chat_history_for_prompt),
    }
    | RunnablePassthrough()
    | {
        "context": RunnableBranch( 
            (   #check for chat history
                lambda x: len(x["chat_history"]) > 0,
                query_rewrite_prompt | model | StrOutputParser(),
            ),
            itemgetter("question"),
        )
        | vector_search_as_retriever
        | RunnableLambda(format_context),
        "formatted_chat_history": itemgetter("formatted_chat_history"),
        "question": itemgetter("question"),
    }
    | prompt
    | model
    | StrOutputParser()
)

format_context function is used to pass only the page_content and not the metadata as that will increase the token size.
metadata is a list of dictionary which I get from the list of similar docs, I want to propagate this to the StrOutputParser() so that I can return the result as a json as below
{
   answer: "..."
   metadata: [{...}{...}]
}

The langchain graph visualization is as follows:
                                +-------------------------------------------------------------+                                    
                                | Parallel<question,chat_history,formatted_chat_history>Input |                                    
                                +-------------------------------------------------------------+                                    
                                      *******                   *                   *******                                        
                              ********                         *                           ********                                
                          ****                                 *                                   ****                            
  +--------------------------------+          +--------------------------------+            +--------------------------------+     
  | Lambda(itemgetter('messages')) |          | Lambda(itemgetter('messages')) |            | Lambda(itemgetter('messages')) |     
  +--------------------------------+          +--------------------------------+            +--------------------------------+     
                  *                                            *                                              *                    
                  *                                            *                                              *                    
                  *                                            *                                              *                    
+-----------------------------------+          +------------------------------+          +---------------------------------------+ 
| Lambda(extract_user_query_string) |          | Lambda(extract_chat_history) |          | Lambda(format_chat_history_for_pro... | 
+-----------------------------------+          +------------------------------+          +---------------------------------------+ 
                                     ********                  *                  *********                                        
                                             *******           *           *******                                                 
                                                    ****       *      *****                                                        
                              +--------------------------------------------------------------+                                     
                              | Parallel<question,chat_history,formatted_chat_history>Output |                                     
                              +--------------------------------------------------------------+                                     
                                                              *                                                                    
                                                              *                                                                    
                                                              *                                                                    
                                                       +-------------+                                                             
                                                       | Passthrough |                                                             
                                                       +-------------+                                                             
                                                              *                                                                    
                                                              *                                                                    
                                                              *                                                                    
                                  +--------------------------------------------------------+                                       
                                  | Parallel<context,formatted_chat_history,question>Input |                                       
                                  +--------------------------------------------------------+                                       
                                    ********                  *                   *********                                        
                            ********                          *                            *******                                 
                        ****                                  *                                   *********                        
              +--------+                                      *                                            ****                    
              | Branch |                                      *                                               *                    
              +--------+                                      *                                               *                    
                  *                                           *                                               *                    
                  *                                           *                                               *                    
                  *                                           *                                               *                    
      +----------------------+                                *                                               *                    
      | VectorStoreRetriever |                                *                                               *                    
      +----------------------+                                *                                               *                    
                  *                                           *                                               *                    
                  *                                           *                                               *                    
                  *                                           *                                               *                    
      +------------------------+          +---------------------------------------+         +--------------------------------+     
      | Lambda(format_context) |          | Lambda(itemgetter('formatted_chat_... |         | Lambda(itemgetter('question')) |     
      +------------------------+******    +---------------------------------------+        *+--------------------------------+     
                                      *******                  *                    *******                                        
                                             ********           *           ********                                               
                                                     ****       *       ****                                                       
                                  +---------------------------------------------------------+                                      
                                  | Parallel<context,formatted_chat_history,question>Output |                                      
                                  +---------------------------------------------------------+                                      
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                     +--------------------+                                                        
                                                     | ChatPromptTemplate |                                                        
                                                     +--------------------+                                                        
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                       +----------------+                                                          
                                                       |   Chat  LLM    |                                                          
                                                       +----------------+                                                          
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                      +-----------------+                                                          
                                                      | StrOutputParser |                                                          
                                                      +-----------------+                                                          
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                                *                                                                  
                                                    +-----------------------+                                                      
                                                    | StrOutputParserOutput |                                                      
                                                    +-----------------------+                                                      

I can do a second call as below, but this will add to the latency of response and hence want to avoid it
retrieve_docs = (lambda x: x["input"]) | retriever

Can someone please suggest me a better method?
Thank you for the help
